# Windows Server 2008 SBS Standard Terminal Services

Tags: windows-terminal-services

I need to set up terminal services on a 2008 SBS Standard server, for 5 users to simply login and run a legacy client.

If I get 5 TS Cals will this be possible?  I was getting some frustrating errors when I installed the TS role, and tried working with the TS licensing snap in. Is this functionality unavailable on the standard edition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to checked Microsoft/MSDN - site?

Comment: ^^ Bad answer, these sorts of comments are strongly discouraged on the Server Fault/Stack Overflow/SuperUser sites. The idea is that people come here for answers.

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsoft, you cannot install terminal services on a SBS 2008 server. Instead, you should install a second server for terminal services. Note that you will still need to purchase the 5 TS CALs for that second server.

See:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd262139%28WS.10%29.aspx

> - Use the second server that is included with Windows SBS 2008 Premium for Terminal Services. You cannot use a server that is running Windows SBS 2008 as a terminal server. Terminal Services does not coexist well with the rest of the applications and services that are included with Windows SBS 2008.

Comment: He clearly states he is using Server 2008 Standard, not SBS.

Comment: ...unless I'm missing something, he states "2008 standard edition SBS"

Comment: Sigh. So he does. My apologies. The correct terminology is "SBS 2008 Standard" or "Premium". I'll update my post to reflect this. Sorry it's early in the morning here after newyears!

Comment: Do you want to change something in your answer so I can remove the downvote? SF won't let you change a vote unless you modify your answer somehow...

Comment: Edited. Thank you, the down-vote had me very sad :)  Happy New Year, just getting our party started here.

Answer (score 0):

As per Evan's answer, you cannot run Terminal Services on 2008 SBS Standard. We run a few SBS scenarios and in the ones where we needed Terminal Server, we purchased the Premium edition for the 2nd Terminal Server machine. The reason? See Point #1 below.

So, if you're running Standard, there is NO WAY you can run Terminal Services on the single server. (You can still run a 2nd server inside Hyper-V so you don't need to shell out for additional hardware)

Once you get the 2nd server, getting a basic terminal server running for 5 people is very straight forward:

1) Very very bad idea to run the TS role on a DC. So if you are, then re-think it right now. Even if you run a virtual TS on the DC using Hyper-V would be a better idea.

2) On the DC, install the TS Licensing role (so that it can be auto-discovered by the TS servers)

3) On the 2008 Standard server, install the TS role (without licensing). For a basic TS you don't need the Session Broker or the other sub-roles.

4) For a basic TS, during the Role setup wizard, you can generally accept the default for everything

5) Install the TS Licenses onto the DC. How to do this depends on your actual form of purchasing the licenses, but generally you: a) Activate the TS Licensing Server by right-clicking on the server in the Licensing snap-in and choosing Activate (make sure you put valid details in, as MS use these details to find you when/if you call for support), b) Actions > Install Licenses, c) follow the wizard

6) Tell the TS to use the DC as its licensing server. Go to the TS Configuration under Administrative Tools > Terminal Server, Right-click the server and go to Properties. It should have found the DC as the license server automatically, but if it hasn't, find the Licensing tab and point it all up.

That's it. If you're going to use RemoteApps (which are awesome in some scenarios) then setting them up is a bit (but not much) more complicated.

Keep in mind that at this stage, the TS has NO security, so you will need to go and configure GPOs to keep it all locked down tight.